# Is it possible to create "object of given id exists" constraint annotation for different classes using spring data repositories?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my project, I have numerous annotations implementing extremely similar logic - they all check if an object of given id exists and are used in DTOs. The validators look like this(enter any class in place of `User`):

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserExistsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserExists, Long> {

private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public boolean isValid(Long id, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return userRepository.existsById(id);
}}
```

I felt stupid after creating the tenth identical annotation, so I came up with an idea using `EntityManager`, where class is passed as annotation's argument.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ObjectOfIdExistsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ObjectOfIdExists, Long> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class clazz;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ObjectOfIdExists constraintAnnotation) {
        clazz = constraintAnnotation.clazz();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Long id, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return entityManager.find(clazz, id) != null;
    }
}
```

However, I've been told that I should not use `EntityManager` in this project (as this would be the only place it is used and it has its own problems).

So my question is:
Is it possible to achieve the same behavior using some kind of generic repository (all of my classes already extend some `BaseEntity`)? If yes, what should the repository look like and what should the constraint validator look like?